# preparing query based on input values in java

Tags: java, jdbc

I dont know whether it is possible or not,But here is my question:

I am getting 13 input fields,based on input

```
 Ex:String firstname=request.getParameter("firstname"); ......
```

I have to prepare sql where clause like if (firstname!=null){ where firstname='test' and ..}

Any advises for this kind of scenario.

Regards,

Raj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to generate queries dynamically, depending on the value of input fields. There are frameworks helping to do that, like [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/). But you could roll your own solution with prepared statements :

```
String query = "select * from foo f";
List<String> clauses = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Object> parameters = new ArrayList<Object>();

if (firstName != null) {
    clauses.add("f.name = ?");
    parameters.add(firstName);
}
// ...
if (!clauses.isEmpty()) {
    query += " where " + StringUtils.join(clauses, " and ");
}

PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
for (int i = 0; i < parameters.size(); i++) {
    ps.setObject(i + 1, paremeters.get(i));
}
```

You could make it even better by supporting SQL types, by using the builder pattern, etc., but you should get the idea with this simple example.

Comment: @JB Nizet:Thanks,Can you give me idea,how to use builder pattern for this problem to avoid checking if else conditions.

Comment: This is a nice solution, the cost of bringing in StringUtils is probably worth it.  You need to space around `"where "` and `"and "`, to avoid `select * from foo fwhere ...`

Comment: The builder pattern could be used to chain method calls, add support for and, or, joins, parentheses, and so on. But whatever the solution, if you want to add a clause if a parameter is not null, you will have to write an if block. You could encapsulate it into a method, though : void addClauseIfNotNull(Object paramValue, String clauseToAdd, List<String> clauses, List<Object> parameters) { if (param != null) {clauses.add(clause); paremeters.add(param);}

Comment: @JB Nizet:Thanks,I agree with your answer.Let me try this.

Comment: @JB Nizet:Still is it posiible to optimize by adding all parameters to the list object,from the list object by iterating all the parameters and exclude those having null values.

Comment: @JB Nizet: How can i do samething with Hibernate Query interface.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using a JDBC connection to your database.  You should use [prepared statements](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), otherwise you are wide open for [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

The second question is how to prevent a WHERE clause involving a field which the user did not supply.  There are many (2^13 == 8192) combinations, so it is not practical to have a different statement for each possible user input.  It would be possible to build the prepared statement dynamically in your case:

```
String statement = "SELECT * FROM " + dbName + "." + tableName;

String condition = " WHERE";
List<String> params = new ArrayList<String>();

if ( firstname  != null ){
    statement += condition + " firstname  = ?";
    condition = " AND";
    params.add(firstname);
}

if ( familyname != null ){
    statement += condition + " familyname  = ?";
    condition = " AND";
    params.add(familyname);
}

connection.prepareStatement(updateString);
```

Then you will need to add the contents of `params` when you execute the prepared statement.

Comment: Thanks,i want approach to prepare only where clause if input value is not null.i will place this where clause in table.

Comment: Hi,I am not going to use this where clause,SP will fetch this where clause i prepared,it will take care rest of the things.So here My question is preparation of where caluse based on input parameters not null.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to dynamically build the query in Java or use a stored procedure that will not filter on a field if it is null.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious about this as well so I created a new answer.  This is what I came up with.  It can be optimized but this does what you want using the Builder pattern.  You can see from my test I pass in a null and it is omitted from the where string.

```
public class WhereBuilder {

private final String requestParm1;
private final String requestParm2;
private final String requestParm3;
private final String requestParm4;
private final String requestParm5;
private StringBuilder whereString = new StringBuilder();

public static class Builder {

    private String requestParm1 = null;
    private String requestParm2 = null;
    private String requestParm3 = null;
    private String requestParm4 = null;
    private String requestParm5 = null;
    private StringBuilder whereString = new StringBuilder("WHERE ");

    public Builder() {}

    public Builder requestParm1(String value) {
        if (value != null) {
            requestParm1 = value;
            whereString.append(" requestParm1 = '"  + requestParm1 + "' AND");
        }
        return this;
    }

    public Builder requestParm2(String value) {
        if (value != null) {
            requestParm2 = value;
            whereString.append(" requestParm2 = '"  + requestParm2 + "' AND");
        }
        return this;
    }

    public Builder requestParm3(String value) {
        if (value != null) {
            requestParm3 = value;
            whereString.append(" requestParm3 = '"  + requestParm3 + "' AND");
        }
        return this;
    }

    public Builder requestParm4(String value) {
        if (value != null) {
            requestParm4 = value;
            whereString.append(" requestParm4 = '"  + requestParm4 + "' AND");
        }
        return this;
    }

    public Builder requestParm5(String value) {
        if (value != null) {
            requestParm5 = value;
            whereString.append(" requestParm5 = '"  + requestParm5 + "' AND");
        }
        return this;
    }


    public WhereBuilder build() {
        return new WhereBuilder(this);
    }

}

private WhereBuilder(Builder builder) {
    requestParm1 = builder.requestParm1;
    requestParm2 = builder.requestParm2;
    requestParm3 = builder.requestParm3;
    requestParm4 = builder.requestParm4;
    requestParm5 = builder.requestParm5;
    whereString = builder.whereString;
}

public String getWhereString() {
    whereString.delete(whereString.length()-3, whereString.length());
    return whereString.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    WhereBuilder wb = new WhereBuilder.Builder().requestParm1("hello").requestParm2("how")
                        .requestParm3("are").requestParm4(null).requestParm5("you").build();
    String whereString = wb.getWhereString();
    System.out.println(whereString);
}
```

}

The output of the main method is

```
WHERE  requestParm1 = 'hello' AND requestParm2 = 'how' AND requestParm3 = 'are' AND requestParm5 = 'you'
```

Comment: Still here also,conditions is checking null values,Is there any utility to exclude null values containing properties,before building the query.

Comment: Wouldn't that utility check for null behind the scenes?  What do you want your call to look like?